# Appending the double quotes for a criteria value having multiple words in spring data solr

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data-solr

I am using spring data solr 1.0.0.Release version. One of my criteria value is having space like **digital still cameras**. But the query string is forming as "digital still cameras" i.e appending the criteria value with double quotations. So that I am not getting the results from solr. Can any one help on this or how to handle these kind of values?

Answer (score 1):

using `critiera.is` will trigger a phrase query so one option would be to split on whitespace `criteria.is("digital", "still", "camera")` or give `criteria.solppy("digital still camera", distance)` a try.

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me but if you don't want double quotes then you can try to escape the special characters with

```
QueryParser.escape(query)
```

where query is your search keyword.

If you want exact results as given keyword the use OR for default operator in schema.xml.

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

Hope that's what you are asking.